# Thunderbird Mail Merge conditional on field ending with a period produces wrong result

Tags: thunderbird

I am trying to make the salutation in my email conditional on whether the recipient has a Job Title or not, but it isn't working properly.
The email is sent, but the salutation is always "Dear {{First Name}},", even though the {{Job Title}} later prints as 'Dr.', which ends with a period.  I need to test for the period character specifically as I have other titles that follow the same rule.

It appears that the regex {{var|$|if|then|else}} isn't working properly.  Would anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

In the body of my mail, I have the following, which always ends up printing "Dear {{First Name}},":

```
Dear {{{{Job Title}}|$|.|{{Job Title}} {{Last Name}}|{{First Name}}}},

Print
{{Job Title}}
{{Last Name}}
{{First Name}}
End
```

When I change the code to the following, the Job Title prints as expected:

```
Dear {{{{Job Title}}|$|.|{{Job Title}}}},

Print
{{Job Title}}
{{Last Name}}
{{First Name}}
End
```

In my CSV file, I have the following:

```
First Name,Last Name,Display Name,Nickname,Primary Email,Secondary Email,Screen Name,Work Phone,Home Phone,Fax Number,Pager Number,Mobile Number,Home Address,Home Address 2,Home City,Home State,Home ZipCode,Home Country,Work Address,Work Address 2,Work City,Work State,Work ZipCode,Work Country,Job Title,Department,Organization,Web Page 1,Web Page 2,Birth Year,Birth Month,Birth Day,Custom 1,Custom 2,Custom 3,Custom 4,Notes
MyFirstName,MyLastName,MyFirstName MyLastName,,me@myemail.com,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Dr.,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexander, the developer of the Mail Merge addon, contacted me about this problem and explained what I had done wrong.  Here is a summary, in my words, that should assist others with the same problem.

You have a syntax issue based on a misunderstanding of the documentation.

The conditional syntax is actually an extension of how variables are represented, rather than a separate construct. Therefore, the statement should be:

```
 Dear {{Job Title|$|.|{{Job Title}} {{Last Name}}|{{First Name}}}},
```

Notice the lack of curly brackets around the first `Job Title`.

Comment: Note that you can use string literals, variables, or combinations of these, as the 'if', 'then', and 'else' parameters.

Comment: It may also be possible to perform indirection on 'var' if you construct 'var' from variables and text, but I haven't tried this.